# Can I reduce this javascript? (multiple image arrays and click Event Listeners)

Tags: javascript

https://jsfiddle.net/mr_antlers/ryLtwcbe/

I have put this together. I simple image swap on click. I've repeated the same block of code for each face element I want to swap. So this block repeats for eyes, then nose, mouth etc...

```
//eyes
var img_eyes = []
img_eyes[0] = "http://guildofone.com/makeneki-neko/img/SVG/eyes0.svg";
img_eyes[1] = "http://guildofone.com/makeneki-neko/img/SVG/eyes1.svg";
img_eyes[2] = "http://guildofone.com/makeneki-neko/img/SVG/eyes2.svg";

//Select all elements on the page with the name attribute equal to VCRImage
var eyes = document.querySelectorAll('[name=eyes]');
for(var i=0; i < eyes.length; i++)
{
  var eyes = eyes[i];
  eyes.addEventListener('click', eyesClicked(), false);
}

function eyesClicked()
{
  var counter = 0;
  return function(event)
  {
    counter++;
    this.src = img_eyes[counter % img_eyes.length];
  }
}
```

I'd like to cut down the repetition in the arrays and the click listeners...

Ideally I'd also like a button to toggle each face attribute.I haven't got to this yet. A random button would be nice too. Any help on these would be appreciated.

Many thanks in advance for guidance on improving this code.

Comment: Pass the array (`img_eyes`) to the `eyesClicked` and maybe rename it to `facePartClicked`. Also, you can simplify `img_eyes` using `Array(3).fill().map((_,i)=>\`http://guildofone.com/makeneki-neko/img/SVG/eyes${i}.svg\`);`

Answer (score 0):

A couple of opportunities:

1. Define features as a list
2. Populate list of feature values dynamically with `new Array(3).fill().map()`
3. Add a listener on the containing element of the image instead of the image itself
4. Maintain the state of the current index on the DOM element using a data attribute (e.g. `data-index`)

```js
const features = [
  {
    element: document.querySelector('.eyes'),
    values: new Array(3).fill().map((value, index) => `http://guildofone.com/makeneki-neko/img/SVG/eyes${index}.svg`),
  },
  {
    element: document.querySelector('.noses'),
    values: new Array(3).fill().map((value, index) => `http://guildofone.com/makeneki-neko/img/SVG/nose${index}.svg`),
  }
];

function initialize() {
  features.forEach(feature => {
    feature.element.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const current = parseInt(feature.element.getAttribute('data-index'), 10);
      const nextIndex = (current + 1) % feature.values.length;
      feature.element.setAttribute('data-index', nextIndex);
      updateFeature(feature);
    });
    
    updateFeature(feature);
  });
}

function updateFeature(feature) {
  const index = feature.element.getAttribute('data-index');
  const img = feature.element.querySelector('img');
  img.src = feature.values[index];
}

initialize();
```

```html
<div class="eyes" data-index="0">
  <img />
</div>
<div class="noses" data-index="0">
  <img />
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks. Will give this a try. This is my preferred solution yet. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just combine all the similar logic into a function and the parts that differ pass in as parameters. In my example, I am passing in the images and the elements to bind an event too - the rest of the implementation within the functions are the same.

```
window.onload = function() {

    //eyes
    var img_eyes = []
    img_eyes[0] = "http://guildofone.com/makeneki-neko/img/SVG/eyes0.svg";
    img_eyes[1] = "http://guildofone.com/makeneki-neko/img/SVG/eyes1.svg";
    img_eyes[2] = "http://guildofone.com/makeneki-neko/img/SVG/eyes2.svg";

    //face
    var img_face = []
    img_face[0] = "http://guildofone.com/makeneki-neko/img/SVG/face0.svg";
    img_face[1] = "http://guildofone.com/makeneki-neko/img/SVG/face1.svg";
    img_face[2] = "http://guildofone.com/makeneki-neko/img/SVG/face2.svg";

    //build the rest of the images


    //add the features 
    addFeature( document.querySelectorAll( "[name=eyes]" ), img_eyes ) 
    addFeature( document.querySelectorAll( "[name=face]" ), img_face ) 
}

function addFeature( features,  imgs ) {

    //add the feature 
    for( var i=0; i < features.length; i++ ) {
        var feature =  features[i];
        feature.addEventListener( "click", featureClicked(), false )
    }
    function featureClicked() {
        let counter = 0;
        return function( event ) {
            counter++;
            this.src = imgs[counter % imgs.length];
        }
    }

}
```